# How to fix “Content not allowed in prolog” Micro service Configuration Exception

Tags: dxa, microservices, deployer-conf, deployerservice

Deployer service starts but quickly stops.

On checking the microservice logs in `C:\SDL\Web\log\`, we found an exception in `C:\SDL\Web\log\deployer-combined\cd_core`

> Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: 
>       org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: 
>       file:///C:/SDL/Web/deployer-combined/deployer-conf.xml; 
>       lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(
>       XMLConfigurationReader.java:128)
>       at
>       com.sdl.delivery.deployer.configuration.DeployerConfigurationLoader.configure(
>       DeployerConfigurationLoader.java:134)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tridion XML configuration files are often manually edited. If you do this, you must always use a TEXT Only editor otherwise your file may get saved with a BOM.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

The Byte Order Mark (BOM) is not handled by Java Xerces XML Parser.

So you get a Configuration Exception “**Content is not allowed in prolog**”

I recommend that you always script changes to the Tridion configuration files or always use a text only editor.

PowerShell example to save configuration files without a Byte Order Mark.

```
#
# RemoveBOM.ps1
#

# Byte Order Mark is not handled by Java Xerces XML Parser

# Typical Exception:
# Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException:
# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
# systemId: file:///C:/SDL/Web/deployer-combined/deployer-conf.xml; 
# lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)   
    $filepath = "C:\sdl\web\deployer-combined\config\deployer-conf.xml"
    $content = Get-Content -Path $filepath
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filepath , $content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

Also read Dominic's excellent Blog on the BOM
http://dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/deployer-conf-xml-barfs-on-the-bom

Comment: Hahaha - Chris - you really should try to keep up with my blog: http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/deployer-conf-xml-barfs-on-the-bom ;-)

Comment: @ Dominic Nice article Dominic. I agree with your comments and I script absolutely everything I can and use PowerShell xml objects to slap the config files into shape. I don't have time to blog so I am putting the fixes I find into Tridion Stack exchange as I go.